# How do I change the edge weight in a graph using the Boost Graph Library?

Tags: c++, boost, graph, boost-graph

I have defined a Graph using the Boost graph library,

```
typedef boost::property<boost::edge_weight_t, int> EdgeWeightProperty;
typedef boost::adjacency_list<boost::listS, boost::vecS,boost::undirectedS,boost::no_property,EdgeWeightProperty> Graph;
```

It is fairly straightforward to add edges using

```
boost::add_edge(vertice1, vertice2, weight, graph);
```

I have yet to figure out how to change the edge weight once it has been set. One possible solution would be to delete the edge and re-add it with the updated the weight value, however, that seems a bit excessive.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

One solution is to do the following

```
typedef boost::adjacency_list<boost::setS, boost::vecS, boost::undirectedS,boost::no_property,EdgeWeightProperty> Graph;
typedef Graph::edge_descriptor Edge;
Graph g;
std::pair<Edge, bool> ed = boost::edge(v1,v2,g);
int weight = get(boost::edge_weight_t(), g, ed.first);
int weightToAdd = 10;
boost::put(boost::edge_weight_t(), g, ed.first, weight+weightToAdd);
```

Comment: Instead of `boost::get` and `boost::put` functions, `int weight = g[ed.first].weight;` and `g[ed.first].weight = weight + weightToAdd;` should also work respectively, if you define edge properties as a struct with the element `weight`

Comment: @agy is it easily possible to use builtin algorithms with weights in an edge property struct instead of the `edge_weight_t()`?

Answer (score 4):

An alternate solution would be to use property maps. Here's an example.

```
// Edge weight.
typedef boost::property<boost::edge_weight_t, int> EdgeWeightProperty;

// Graph.
typedef boost::adjacency_list< boost::listS,
                               boost::vecS,
                               boost::undirectedS,
                               boost::no_property,
                               EdgeWeightProperty > Graph;

// Vertex descriptor.
typedef typename boost::graph_traits<Graph>::vertex_descriptor Vertex;

// The Graph object
Graph g;

// Populates the graph.
Vertex v1 = boost::add_vertex(g);
Vertex v2 = boost::add_vertex(g);
Vertex v3 = boost::add_vertex(g);
boost::add_edge(v1, v2, EdgeWeightProperty(2), g);
boost::add_edge(v1, v3, EdgeWeightProperty(4), g);
boost::add_edge(v2, v3, EdgeWeightProperty(5), g);

// The property map associated with the weights.
boost::property_map < Graph,
                      boost::edge_weight_t >::type EdgeWeightMap = get(boost::edge_weight, g);

// Loops over all edges and add 10 to their weight.
boost::graph_traits< Graph >::edge_iterator e_it, e_end;
for(std::tie(e_it, e_end) = boost::edges(g); e_it != e_end; ++e_it)
{
  EdgeWeightMap[*e_it] += 10;
}

// Prints the weighted edgelist.
for(std::tie(e_it, e_end) = boost::edges(g); e_it != e_end; ++e_it)
{
  std::cout << boost::source(*e_it, g) << " "
            << boost::target(*e_it, g) << " "
            << EdgeWeightMap[*e_it] << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: What if my weight is a function of the source and end vertices of the edge?

Comment: @Jim Do you mean: What if the weights were a function of some variable (ex. state) of the vertices? Because right now, since each edge is attached to two nodes, the weight is technically a function both vertices. And if the order "source/target" were important, you could use bidirectional graphs.